# How do I activate “The Doctor Who Cloned Me” DLC in Duke Nukem Forever in Steam?

Tags: steam, duke-nukem-forever

I bought the add-on DLC, and Steam shows me that I have it. But I don’t see any way to actually play the damn thing. My Library in Steam only shows the main DNF game, and once I launch it, it still has the regular game stuff only.

What do I need to do to play the extra content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion pack is Windows only. It does not show up on a Mac where I was trying to use it. In Windows, it shows up under “Downloadable Content” menu in the game.